# Select rows from a DataFrame based on a values in another dataframe and updating one of the column with values according to the second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, updating

I have two Dataframes df and df1.

Main DataFrame is as follows:
DF:

```
    start   end price
0   A   Z   1
1   B   Y   2
2   C   X   3
3   A   Z   4
4   D   W   5
```

Second DataFrame:
DF1:

```
start   end price
    0   A   Z   100
    1   B   Y   200
```

I want the main dataframe df to update the values in 'price' columns based on the start and end in df1. it should update column value for all the rows having the same start and end as in df1.
DF:

```
start   end price
0   A   Z   100
1   B   Y   200
2   C   X   3
3   A   Z   100
4   D   W   5
```

(all A-Z and B-Y in df should get updated). Is there anyway I can get this output ? In reality the datframes have more columns but I want to update only one column(eg.'Price').

Answer (score 2):

First, you can merge:

```
s = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['start', 'end'], right_on=['start', 'end'], how='left')
```

Then you can `fillna` and index your desired columns:

```
s.assign(price=s.price_y.fillna(s.price_x))[['start', 'end', 'price']]
```

```
  start end  price
0     A   Z  100.0
1     B   Y  200.0
2     C   X    3.0
3     A   Z  100.0
4     D   W    5.0
```

Comment: thaks. I have multiple columns in the main dataframe df (except start and end), I want that too in the result. how can I modify your code to get all columns from the main dataframe df.

Answer (score 2):

Using `update`

```
df=df.set_index(['start','end'])
df.update(df1.set_index(['start','end']))
df.reset_index()
Out[99]: 
  start end  price
0     A   Z  100.0
1     B   Y  200.0
2     C   X    3.0
3     A   Z  100.0
4     D   W    5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `merge`

```
df.drop('price', 1).merge(df1, 'left').fillna(df)

  start end  price
0     A   Z  100.0
1     B   Y  200.0
2     C   X    3.0
3     A   Z  100.0
4     D   W    5.0
```

---

1. I'm going to merge on `['start', 'end']` and that pesky `price` is going to get in my way.  So, I drop it.
2. I need to preserve `df` index because I have that repeat of `'A'` and `'Z'`.  So, I use a `'left'` `merge`
3. Now my missing elements can be filled back in with `df`

Comment: Very nice, much cleaner

Comment: It gives me the exact output, but when I run it in a loop( in my code df1 keeps changing and makes updates to the mail dataframe df ), it gave me error saying    " TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' ".

Comment: Loop?  What?  Why?  I have no idea what you are doing in your loop. I’d suggest accepting one of these answers and asking a new question that addresses the loop issue.